# How do I make a straight skeleton with qtree?

Tags: tikz-qtree, qtree

I have the following tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree [.A [.a ] [.B [.A ] [.a ] ] ]


\end{document}
```

and I would like the A -> B -> A skeleton to be a straight line (meaning, the angle between the branches should be different, so that A -> B -> A goes straight down).

Also, I would like to have a dashed curvy line connecting between the two "a"s. Are those two things possible?

(I don't mind using tikz-qtree instead if needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: As the eagle flies from A through B to another A]

I did this with Forest because it makes it easy. Perhaps `tikz-qtree` offers something similar, but Forest is generally more capable in this regard.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\Forest{[A[a][B, calign with current [A, calign with current][a]]]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is strange - I have to delete the .aux file every time to get it to show the tree properly. Otherwise, the whole page becomes blank and stuff disappears. I am unable to create a MWE, unfortunately, it is in a bigger document.

Comment: added a question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426176/why-the-following-doesnt-render-well-clash-with-tikz-and-forest